# Using Ng-select clearable for only one field

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

The following code is for two filters. However, when you click the clear button in one of the filters, both filters get cleared. Is there a way to use the [clearable] property so that only the clicked filter gets cleared?

```xhtml
<div class="filter-item" *ngFor="let datum of data" [ngClass]="{'select-filter': selectedItem && selectedItem?.label}'>

  <div class="title">
    <span>{{ datum.key }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="select">
    <ng-select #select [placeholder]="'Select'" [items]="datum.data" [multiple]="false" 
     bindLabel="label" [(ngModel)]="datum.selectedItems" appendTo="body" 
     (change)="onChange($event, datum)">
    </ng-select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the other ngselect? I can see only one ngselect here in the code.

Comment: You may also put the example code here in : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x8nx9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 

That would help others to see the realtime issue.

Comment: @jaypalSodha there is a loop at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

i think you did something wrong with config here is the latest `ng-select` example you can take a look in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ep8tz6)

just click on `Ng Select` button.

**Note**: `clearable` is by default true